# max microSD capacity? how is this controlled?

Tags: hardware

So I'm looking at a cheap android phone ($30) to use as an MP3 player while at the gym. I just saw several from the local carriers (perhaps same phone but rebranded?) and they advertised the phone as having a max of 32GB size for the microSD.

How is the max controlled? is this controlled by the SoC used? or perhaps another chip? I was hoping to use a 64GB one I already have.

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple (micro)SD standards and not all devices support all of them. Up to 4GB is normal microSD, up to 32GB is microSDHC and above is microSDXC (including the Ultra-HighSpeed extension).

Comment: is that a function of the SoC then?

Comment: Basically, yes, but from experience, many devices support capacities greater than advertised (my old S5230 Star supports 64GB no problem, the last time I checked, even though it's not advertised)